# Handle Event on pressing on tabbar item if its activated

Tags: iphone, select, tabbar

Hello
Usually if you are in a UINavigation Hirarchy with a Tabbar-Navigationbar Combination and you press on a Tabbar Item you will get back to the rootviewControler.

I need to get this event -> pressing on a tabbar item if its activated. Is this somehow possible to catch that event?

best regards

Answer (score 1):

i got it:

```
    //NSLog(@"TabItem %@ tapped with tag: %d", viewController.tbItem.title, viewController.tbItem.tag);
if ([viewController.tbItem.title isEqualToString:NSLocalizedString(@"FEATURE_NEARBY", nil)]) {
    if([((MyNavigationController*)(self.selectedViewController)).visibleViewController isKindOfClass:[MyViewController class]]){
    [(MyViewController*)((MyNavigationController*)(self.selectedViewController)).visibleViewController myFunction];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your view controller conform to the `UITabBarDelegate` protocol and implement `tabBar:didSelectItem:`  I usually set the UITabBarItems with tags that I can use in the code to decide what to do.

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITabBarDelegate> 
{
}
@end

- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
    enum {
        FooButton = 1,  // Presumably you set these up in IB or in code elsewhere
        BarButton,
        BazButton
    };

    switch( item.tag ) {
        case FooButton:
            [self doTheFooThing];
        break;
        // ... Other cases here
    }
}
```

Comment: i am already doing this. But thios also fires if i press on the tabbar item when its not selected yet. I need to trigger an event that fires when i tap on a TabItem when its already selected. If go from one tap to another this event shouldn't fire.

Comment: That will fire whether or not you tap on an item that's already selected.  Maybe you could put code in there to ignore the tap if it was on an item that wasn't already selected?